# Request without URL Encode - Chrome/Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, urlencode

Is there anyway we can send request from browser bypassing Default URL encode given by Chrome and Firefox without using xmlhttprequest using any tag attributes or redirect or something like that ?

Update: It is a GET request I am trying to send.

Comment: What type of request do you want to send? `GET`, `POST`, ...?

Comment: Sorry I  missed that to mention. It is GET request.

Comment: This link will help you :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247483/http-get-request-in-javascript

Comment: @RaviHirani :| That is how to make requests. I want to bypass default URL encode given by Chrome/Firefox. Is there any way ?

Comment: Why do you need to bypass default URL encoding? What is it wrong with it?